# Show that if $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is invertible then $\exists k$ such that $a^k = 1$ (mod n)

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is invertible then $\exists k$ such that $a^k = 1$ (mod n)

I am having trouble knowing where to start.

Comment: Assume not, ...

Comment: If $a$ is invertible, then $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$, i.e. the group of invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Since this group is finite, any element must have a finite order.

Comment: List the powers $a,a^2,a^3,\cdots \pmod n$.  That list can't be infinite so $a^i\equiv a^j\pmod n$ for some $i>j$.  Then....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_n$ , we have $gcd(a,n)=1$ and due to Euler's theorem we have $$a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$$ where $\phi$ is the totient-function.

Answer (score 1):

The members of the sequence $(a^m)_{m\in \mathbb N}$ cannot all be mutually incongruent, modulo $n,$ as each $a^m$ is congruent, modulo $n,$ to a member of the finite set $\{0,1,...,n-1\}.$

So there exist $m,m'\in \mathbb N$ with $m'-m>0$ and $a^m\equiv a^{m'} \pmod n.$

If there exists $b\in \mathbb Z$ with $ba\equiv 1\pmod n $ then $b^ma^m\equiv 1 \pmod n,$ so $$1\equiv b^ma^m\equiv b^ma^{m'}\equiv b^ma^ma^{m'-m}\equiv a^{m'-m}\pmod n.$$

We could also replace the sequence $(a^m)_{m\in \mathbb N}$ in the first sentence above, with the finite sequence $(a^m)_{1\leq m\leq n+1},$ and apply the Pigeon-Hole Principle, to derive the second sentence above.